# Error while Using a function of an existing package in R with SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

So, I installed SparkR using the steps given on the link: "https://amplab-extras.github.io/SparkR-pkg/". And I have installed it from Github repository using the direct command given on the website. Now, here goes my code:

```
library(SparkR)
sc <- sparkR.init(master="local")
files <- paste0("NP",1:10,".txt")
func.clique <- function(file)
{
    w <- read.table(file)
    g <- graph.edgelist(cbind(as.character(w$V1),as.character(w$V2)))
    plot(g)
    cli <- cliques(g)
    return (cli)
}
includePackage(sc, igraph)
cliquevalues <- sapply(files,func.clique)
```

Now, this code works absolutely fine (without SparkR commands in RStudio) when I use the `igraph` library directly. But now, when I execute it, it says, `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : could not find function "graph.edgelist"`. What might be the possible reason for this? I have tried placing the `includePackage` at several places but it seems to be of no help. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `SparkR` replaces `sapply()` as well as `lapply()`? What if you switched? I'm guessing the `sapply()` is just running locally so it expects `library(igraph)` in your current environment. But i must admit i don't use `SparkR` so i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Well, I tried with both `sapply` and `lapply` but still get the same error.

Comment: Is it possible that SparkR uses a different library location than where you have the `igraph` package installed to?

Comment: @ForrestR.Stevens, it worked fine whenever I used to use it in RStudio with my normal code. I used to set any location and I never had a problem. However, I still gave this a try and changed my work location to the place where SparkR shell is there (`bin`). It still didn't work.

Comment: Just for a refference: https://amplab-extras.github.io/SparkR-pkg/ is no longer maintained. From Spark 1.4 SparkR is shipped with Spark itself but it has completely different and rather limited API.

Comment: @zero323, is there any place where I can get any reference for the new one?

Comment: You can try [Spark SQL and DataFrame Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html). To be honest though it is probably not worth the time. API is rather limited, docs close to nonexistent and it lacks (or very well hides) some basic functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would try placing `library(igraph)` inside the closure function, along with other libraries that are not part of the base packages. Something like:

```
func.clique <- function(file) {

    library(igraph)

    w <- read.table(file)
    g <- graph.edgelist(cbind(as.character(w$V1),as.character(w$V2)))
    plot(g)
    cli <- cliques(g)
    return (cli)
}
```